# Example on how to use TFileTransport in Thrift (Client/Server)

Tags: java, thrift

Is there anyone who managed to get TFileTransport as a transport layer, to work? I've tried but since there is no documentation (or have I not found it?) for this, I am not able to make it work.

If anyone have been more successful and could provide some sample code, it would be great.

**edit:**

What I've tried so far:

```
public class FileThriftServer {

public static void startThriftServer(
        ThriftDataBenchmark.Processor<ThriftDataBenchmarkHandler> processor) {
    try {

        File input = new File("ThriftFile.in");
        if(!input.exists()){
            input.createNewFile();
        }

        File output = new File("ThriftFile.out");
        if(!output.exists()){
            output.createNewFile();
        }

        TFileTransport inputFileTransport = new TFileTransport(input.getAbsolutePath(), true);
        TFileTransport outputFileTransport = new TFileTransport(output.getAbsolutePath(), false);

        inputFileTransport.open();
        outputFileTransport.open();

        TFileProcessor fProcessor = 
                new TFileProcessor(processor, new TJSONProtocol.Factory(), inputFileTransport, outputFileTransport);
        //  this results in error in case I don't call those open methods above
        fProcessor.processChunk();

        System.out.println("File Thrift service started ...");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // ThriftDataBenchmarkHandler is an implementation of my test service
    startThriftServer(new ThriftDataBenchmark.Processor<ThriftDataBenchmarkHandler>(
            new ThriftDataBenchmarkHandler()));
}
}
```

Now I don't know if I am even on a good way, maybe I misunderstood the concept of this transport (again, it is not documented). I would expect I start the server by some method now which will listen on the input file. When clients put there something, it would process it and write the answer to output file (I didn't try to write client yet since this peace of code just executes and exists, it is obviously not right).

**edit 2:**

Ok, so if I understand it right, this code is ok and it should process one request of the client, if it's there. So I am moving to the client side, doing something like this:

```
        File input = new File(THRIFT_INPUT_FILE_PATH);
        if (!input.exists()) {
            input.createNewFile();
        }

        TTransport transport = new TFileTransport(input.getAbsolutePath(),
                false);

        TProtocol protocol = new TJSONProtocol(transport);
        ThriftDataBenchmark.Client client = new ThriftDataBenchmark.Client(
                protocol);

        // my testing service, the parameters are not important
        SimpleCompany company = client.getSimpleCompanyData("token", 42);
```

Unfortunatelly calling `getSimpleCompanyData` results in:

```
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Not Supported
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFileTransport.write(TFileTransport.java:572)
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.write(TTransport.java:105)
at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TJSONProtocol.writeJSONArrayStart(TJSONProtocol.java:476)
at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TJSONProtocol.writeMessageBegin(TJSONProtocol.java:487)
at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.sendBase(TServiceClient.java:62)
```

It's a bit confusing that server side requires input and output transport but on the client side, it only accepts one. How does it read an answer and from where?

Let's not move into some extra logic of checking the file for changes, if it's not already part of Thrift. I'll be ok at this point by doing it manually in sense of: running the client first, then running the server side.

Comment: BTW here: http://thrift-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/thrift-stack.html it is said that TFileTransport acutally doesn't come with version for Java, however it must be old because with Thrift 0.9.1 you can see the class is present.

Comment: It could be helpful if you could be more specific on (a) what you tried and (b) what "doesn't work" actually means. (BTW, I always wonder why even people actually working in the IT industry are not able to give a profound problem description. How can you expect this from your users/customers?)

Comment: a) I can add something I've tried. Reason I didn't do it is because it could only mislead someone else, but ok, I'll do it.
b) Are you familiar with Thrift? Because your question suggest you are not. It is a technology for creating services, by "work", I mean there is a client and server and the client is able to call servers methods and get a response. I believe this is obvious from what I may expect from working service and it didn't need extra description. I don't understand your comment on what am I expecting from my customers???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would expect I start the server by some method now which will listen on the input file. When clients put there something, it would process it and write the answer to output file (I didn't try to write client yet since this peace of code just executes and exists, it is obviously not right).

That's exactly right. In particular, the `fProcessor.processChunk()` call you used will process exactly one chunk (the current one). The whole class looks as designed around the assumption that the file size is static and does not change over time. However, the underlying `TFileTransport` supports what's called a `tailPolicy`, used when a read call hits `EOF`:

```
public class TFileTransport extends TTransport {

    public static enum tailPolicy {

      NOWAIT(0, 0),
      WAIT_FOREVER(500, -1);

      /**
       * Time in milliseconds to sleep before next read
       * If 0, no sleep
       */
      public final int timeout_;

      /**
       * Number of retries before giving up
       * if 0, no retries
       * if -1, retry forever
       */
      public final int retries_;

      // ... ctor ...
    }


    /**
     * Current tailing policy
     */
    tailPolicy currentPolicy_ = tailPolicy.NOWAIT;
```

Another option to get it to work could be calling `fProcessor.processChunk(int chunkNum)`, watching the file contents separately and repeat the calls when new data come in. It's certainly not such a bad idea to use the `TFileProcessor` as a starting point and improve it as needed.

```
//  this results in error in case I don't call those open methods above
fProcessor.processChunk();
```

Opening the transports before using is fine. I think that part is ok.

```
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Not Supported
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFileTransport.write(TFileTransport.java:572)
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.write(TTransport.java:105)
```

Unfortunately, that seems pretty correct yet. The only place where writing is implemented is the code in the C++ library. Both Java and D only support reading (yet).

Comment: Nice, so at least I know the server side should work. Unfortunately I am still not able to do a round trip of exchanging the information, please check my edit 2.

Comment: I just added some more information regarding the read side that I missed before. Regarding write, the code is really that incomplete. Looks as if someone stopped at the point where things were enough for his/her specific purpose.